# How to Json convert normal string using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have the below result, I want its show normal words like  **description: hello test, address:London** in nodejs

```
delta result {"description":"HELLO Description Edit","address":{"street_address":"Business Edit","city":"Bradford EDIT"}}
```

I want like  **description: hello test, address:London**

```
var pusthistory = new JobHistory({ changetype: 'Updated', details:  JSON.stringify(delta) });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is to convert a JSON to a normal string,

use 
[**JSON.stringify()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method to do that

Or if you want to parse `JSON string to JSON`,

You can parse it using [**JSON.parse()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)